# use the for loop in the if any() statement as the next condition

Tags: python

Say I have a list of class objects, where each class object has a public attribute 'value' which contains an int. Is it possible to write an 'if any()' statement followed by the for loop used in the conditional?

```
def func(prefix: List):
    if any(subtree.value == prefix[0] for subtree in self.subtrees):
        # and then access the subtree that contained value equivalent to prefix[0]
        subtree.value += prefix[0]
```

currently I'll have to write another for loop which then feels so redundant for my if statement..

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with a generator inside of `any()`, since that namespace isn't shared outside of `any`, but you can do it with an equivalent `for` loop and `break`...

```
def func(prefix: List):
    for subtree in self.subtrees:
        if subtree.value == prefix[0]:
            subtree.value += prefix[0]
            break
```